# How to upload image with carrierwave and cloudinary gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

When i tried to upload image using `carrierwave` and `cloudinary` in rails 
I'm getting the error:

> private method `write_uploader' called for object.

Can anyone help me out of this. I created `ImageUploder` using `carrierwave`, and in gallery model O put `mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader`

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Cloudinary's sample project which demonstrates image uploads with CarrierWave:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/tree/master/samples/photo_album